# Resolving merge conflict in a pull request locally

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm using bit-bucket. I have a repository called Cosmo in a bit-bucket group. I took a folk of it and worked in my fork. Let's call it Cosmo-Folk. Cosmo has 2 branches called develop and master. Develop is used to put the latest code from all the developers. Later the admin check the develop and merge it to master so it will trigger CI CD servers.

In my Cosmo-Folk I have the master and my feature branch (devops). I take the latest code from Cosmo (develop) to my master. Then merge it to my feature branch (which I'm currently working).

Then After working I do the pulls from my remote called origin (cloud Cosmo-Folk) and resolve conflicts and sync it with my local repository. Which means Cosmo-folk and my PC has the same code now. After all that I create a pull request from Cosmo-Folk/feature/devops -> Cosmo/develop. Then I get merge conflicts before merging. This is explained in the image bellow.

[image]

So my question is as in bit-bucket I can't edit files I need to pull the conflict locally and resolve it, and then push or do what ever to make that merge conflict go away and merge the pull request to Cosmo/develop. How can I do that? I'm new to git and explanation with the answer will be valuable. Thank you!

Comment: The typical thing to do here would be to checkout the feature branch, then pull the target branch (i.e. the branch into which you want to merge).  This will give you _local_ merge conflicts, on your computer, which you may then merge.  Afterwards, update your pull request by pushing, and the warning message should go away.

Comment: Also, why the GitHub tag?

Answer (score 1):

From your question what i understood is that you are currently working on cosmo-folk branch in your local and when you try to push your changes to the develop branch you are getting conflicts.

That usually happens when someone else has done some changes in the same file that you are trying to push. To resolve that do the following steps:-

- Checkout to the develop branch
- Take the latest pull
- checkout back to the branch you were trying to push changes from
- Run `git merge develop`
- Now whatever ide you are using will show you the merge conflicts resolve them and stage and commit the changes
- now push the changes and raise a pull request

I hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1**: Checkout `Cosmo-Folk/feature/devops` or branch that you want to merge in local.

`git checkout <branch you want to merge>`

**Step 2**: merge master/develop branch in which you want to merge to local

`git merge origin develop` or `git merge origin master` or `git merge origin <branch you want to merge with you current checkout branch>`

**Step 3**: It will show you all conflicted files that you can see in BitBucket. Resolve conflicts in local and then commit the conflicted files.

`git add <resolved files>`

`git commit -m "<message to be tracked>"`

`git push`